# iPad Split View Not Showing BarButtonItem When Switching View Controllers in Master View Controller

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am quite new to iPad Development, so please forgive my questions that might seem a little obvious.

I have an existing application for the iPhone which I am converting to a universal app for the iPad version.

The UI is going to be simple.

A `Split View Controller` where the `Master` represents a Static `UITableView` (Person, Timeline, Event, Date) for the user to select. The `Detail` will of course display whichever cell was selected in the `UITableView Master`. Both the `Detail` and `Master` have been created in Storyboard and are both NavigationControllers.

I am trying to do the common aspect of: Landscape mode shows both the `Master` and `Detail` View, while Portrait shows only the `Detail` View, but with a `UIBarButtonItem` that pops out the `Master` when requested.

**Issue**

When I rotate from `Landscape` to `Portrait`, the `UIBarButtonItem` is visible and I can press it to bring out the `Master` View in Portrait mode.

**In portrait mode, if I bring out the button and select a different cell from the `Master` View, when I dismiss the `Master` by tapping anywhere in the `Detail` View, it doesn't now show the `UIBarButton`.**

I am following http://www.dharmaworks.net/Consulting/switching-detail-views-in-uisplitviewcontroller-with-ios7/ as a way to get try get this working.

**Code**

**MasterTableView:**

```
#pragma mark - Split View Delegate
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    UINavigationController *navController = [[[self splitViewController ] viewControllers ] lastObject ];
    id vc = [[navController viewControllers] firstObject];

    [vc setSplitViewButton:barButtonItem forPopoverController:popoverController];
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    UINavigationController *navController = [[[self splitViewController ] viewControllers ] lastObject ];
    id vc = [[navController viewControllers] firstObject];

    [vc setSplitViewButton:nil forPopoverController:nil];
}
```

**SplitViewPresenter Protocol**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *splitViewBarButtonItem;
-(void)setSplitViewButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)splitViewButton forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController;
```

**Detail View**

```
-(void) turnSplitViewButtonOn: (UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *) popoverController {
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    _splitViewBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = (MasterTableViewController *)popoverController;
}

-(void)turnSplitViewButtonOff
{
    NSLog(@"SplitViewButtonOff Called");
    // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    _splitViewBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.masterPopoverController = nil;

}

-(void) setSplitViewButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)splitViewButton forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    NSLog(@"Split View Being Called");
    if (splitViewButton != _splitViewBarButtonItem) {
        if (splitViewButton) {
            NSLog(@"Split View Button Being Called");
            [self turnSplitViewButtonOn:splitViewButton forPopoverController:popoverController];
        } else {
            [self turnSplitViewButtonOff];
            NSLog(@"Split View Button Not Being Called");
        }
    }
}
```

The .h file of the Detail View is declared to use the SplitViewPresenter.

**Update**

I understand why this is occurring. The setter is only getting called when I rotate from the Landscape to Portrait mode. My question is, how do I get this to work without the rotation? Also, within the link above that I have followed, I have not implemented any of the didSelectRow code. Should I be doing that?

Any guidance on this would really be appreciated.